# How to determine object's owner in Objective-C program?

Tags: objective-c

Are there any tools available as part of XCode4 that per given object will tell you "who owns it at any time?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.   The Allocaitons instrument can answer that.  Turn on retain count tracking and run your app.  You can then click through any object (you'll typically only want to track live allocations) and see an inventory of all retains/releases related to that object.

All retains not balanced by a release from the same object indicates an ownership relationship.

It isn't 100% precise, but it works well enough (and is improving with each release).

Comment: Could you please illustrate with example and a screenshot or an object "changing hands"?

Comment: If you alloc/init a *View subclass, then add it is a subview of a view, it'll be retained (and you must release it if you no longer wish to maintain a reference).